# Why is my navbar from bootstrap disappearing when in mobile?

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using bootstrap's navbar and it shows perfectly on a large screen, but when it gets to mobile, it disappears completely.

I've tried @media and changing the sizes but it's not really working.

```
 **css**

    #navbar {display: inline-block;  background-color: #ffffff;  color: #FFFFFF;}
    #navbar a:link  {outline: 0;}
    #navbar a:visited {color: #101010; margin:2px; padding: 5px;}
    #navbar a:active,  
    #navbar a:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5; color: #C21315;text-decoration: none; outline: 0;} 
    /* NAVIGATION BAR LINKS */
    #navbar li a { display: inline-block; overflow:visible; }
    #navbar li { display: inline-block; overflow:visible; }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
    #navbar {display: block;}
     }

    **Bootstrap navbar**
     <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle-"collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only"> Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a style=" font-size: 1.1em; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 35px;" href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Home</span></a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a style=" font-size: 1.3em; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 35px;" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              About </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
              <li><a href="#">Our Library</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action2</a></li>    
              <li><a href="#">Action3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved (somewhat)
I needed to add .navbar-toggle and .navbar-toggle .icon-barin the css

Answer (score 0):

Does the space collapse or does it just look hidden?

Comment: No it doesn't collapse, it just looks hidden.

Comment: Okay then try class = navbar-toggle alone in your button. You have navbar-toggle collapsed

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem. Works fine on my machine. Can you paste the whole HTML file here? (including the javascript and css imports). If you are not using the cdn (you have your .js and .css files downloaded and linked from some folder, just write the version of these imported files)